# Git using for aliases different shell than bash

Tags: bash, git, alias

I am learning git for some time, recently I have been using aliases. Everything was working, until last time. My example alias stopped working ( git simple-commit works fine )

```
simple-loop = "!simpleLoop() { NAME=$1; i="1"; while [ $i -le $2 ]; do git simple-commit $NAME$i; i=$[$i+1]; done; }; simpleLoop"
```

I am getting fatal in terminal

```
simpleLoop() { NAME=$1; i=1; while [ $i -le $2 ]; do git simple-commit $NAME$i; i=$[$i+1]; done; }; 
simpleLoop: 1: [: Illegal number: $[1+1]
```

It looks like git not using bash shell.
Any idea what is going on ?

Comment: `$[$i+1]` is valid *bash* syntax, but not valid *POSIX shell* syntax. Git uses `/bin/sh` on Unix-like systems (including Linux) and that may be a POSIX shell variant rather than a bash variant. Use the double parentheses syntax as it's much more widely implemented.

Comment: `$[...]` is (and has been for a very long time) obsolete in `bash`; use `$((...))` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested a simplified version of that alias:

```
aa = "!simpleLoop() { i="1"; while [ $i -le "4" ]; do echo $i; i=$[$i+1]; done; }; simpleLoop"
```

And `git aa` does give the expected result:

```
D:\git\>git aa
1
2
3
4
```

To be sure, assuming Git for Windows, test your alias in a `CMD` session with a simplified `PATH`:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```

You can also use a number for `i` (`i=1` instead of `"1"`) and use [other syntax to increment that variable](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-increment-decrement-variable/) (like `i=$((i+1))`)